# Custom Nav Title offset ios 11

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem, ios11, titlebar

I have a custom navigation item title that is simply two labels, one on top of the other, loaded from a .xib file.

[image]

It's loaded by calling this:

```
class Utilities {
  /// Title and subtitle format custom title in Navigation bar.  Top and bottom text are centered on one another.
  ///
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - navigationItem: The receiving controller's navigation item.
  ///   - titleText: Top text to be displayed a little larger and more bold.
  ///   - subtitleText: Bottom text to be displayed a little smaller and less bold.
  class func addCustomNavigationTitle(navigationItem: UINavigationItem, titleText: String, subtitleText: String) {
      let customNavigationTitleView =   LabelSubLabelCustomHeaderView.instanceFromNib() as! LabelSubLabelCustomHeaderView
      customNavigationTitleView.titleLabel.text = titleText
      customNavigationTitleView.dateLabel.text = subtitleText
      navigationItem.titleView = customNavigationTitleView
  }
  ...
}
```

It's defined as this:

```
class LabelSubLabelCustomHeaderView: UIView {
  @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel!

  class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
      return UINib(nibName: "LabelSubLabelCustomHeaderView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
  }
}
```

Now, it's pushed down by exactly 22 pixels, which hides the bottom label.

I have to set the frame of this view in the viewDidAppear in order to set it straight.  I tried viewWillAppear and several other things.  I'm literally having to hide it, set it, then show it, which is clearly not right.

Prior to iOS 11, this worked no problem.

Here it is now, without my hack fix, which I hope I can make right:

[image]

And here is what it should look like, what it looked like prior to iOS 10, and how it looks with my hack fix:

[image]

Also please note that when the unwind segue is animating, the view goes back to the incorrect frame, being 22 pixels too low.  **How can I fix this?** Thanks for any help in advance.

Edit: More detailed constraint info:

[image: View]
[image: DateLabel]

[image: TitleLabel]

Comment: I believe the error/solution will be in your layout constraints, any chance you could show what you have defined so far?

Comment: Thanks.  That's why I put the screenshot showing the constraints but I can go ahead and show a more detailed screenshot...  I'll edit the original post, I guess...

Comment: Okay, I put more screenshots.  Note that this is being loaded from .xib and set as a Navigation Item custom title view.  I do not know how to set the constraints on the loaded view, or if that's even possible.  I would think that the Navigation Item does that for me.  At any rate, it worked fine with the current constraints prior to iOS 11.

Comment: From what I can tell, your titleView doesn't have any height constraint, there does not seem to be a constraint to ensure the bottom of the "Label Sub Label Custom Header" is lower or equal to the "Date Label".  I believe that this may become obvious if you enable clipping on the header view, your date label may just be outside of the bounds of the header view and still be visible since it is not clipped.

Comment: Well yes, that's what is happening.  It's proven in my 'hack fix', with which I'm basically forcing the view up 22 pixels.  The peculiarity is the fact that I had no problems with this at all prior to iOS 11.  If it's a constraints issue, how do I set constraints to the view that's loaded from the nib?  That view does not have any superview in the nib file itself.  I would have a hard time believing that I need to manually program the constraints and add them to the constraints array (constraining it to the nav bar content view), unless this is a known thing introduced in iOS 11 that I missed.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this before.  I just ran it on the iOS 10.3 Simulator and the view is offset in iOS 11 in particular.  My 'hack-fix' causes the view to be up by 22 pixels instead of down.  Taking the hack-fix away, it works perfectly and as I would expect it to.  This is definitely iOS 11 specific.

Comment: If you are confident this is a bug in iOS 11, you should open up a ticket with Apple. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a layout constraint in your custom view title Xib enforcing a minimum distance between the lower label to the safe area of the view. For a complete working example on iOS 10/11, see https://github.com/ekscrypto/Swift-Tutorial-Custom-Title-View

Comment: Thank you for the help and the example project.  Much appreciated.  I have another problem now, with your example project that maybe you can help with.  I'll start a new thread.  See link coming up soon.

Comment: I tried to checkout your project so I could push the changes but they are simple.  I added a button that pushes a new view controller.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415168/custom-title-view-not-centered

Comment: It's working well for iOS 11 but not working well for iOS 10 before.