# Custom Title View not Centered in iOS 10

Tags: ios, ios10, uinavigationitem

This post is a separate topic but related to [Custom Nav Title offset ios 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332857/custom-nav-title-offset-ios-11/46352164#46352164)

I created a new thread because it is a separate issue.

[image]

From project: https://github.com/ekscrypto/Swift-Tutorial-Custom-Title-View

To recreate the problem, simply put a button on the existing Root View Controller that pushes another view controller.  The "< Back" button scoots the title over, which makes it terribly uncentered.  How can I fix this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple change required to support earlier versions of iOS; you should properly resize your custom title view to be the expected width its actually going to be. iOS 11 attempts to resize the width of the title view to fit the available space based on the constraints but iOS 10 and below will try to maintain the size of the view as much as possible.

The solution is therefore to open the MyCustomTitleView.xib file, and to set the width of the MyCustomTitleView to something reasonable like 180pt.

Cheers!

Comment: I just downloaded and tested your project and I'm seeing that it is correct with no problem.  I don't know why this would matter, but what I actually did is, I changed the root view controller to be the new view controller and connected the button on the new view controller to push the controller that already existed.

Comment: I don't normally use a github account but let me get that going so I can send you a copy of my project.

Comment: Oh wow, okay.  Mine and yours are actually the same.  Turns out that this is only going to occur on iOS 10.

Comment: @BrandonMantzey I cleaned and ran your project using Xcode 9 GM, iOS 11 iPhone X simulator.. everything is behaving as expected with the title view properly centered.

Comment: @BrandonMantzey might want to update your question indicating this is related to iOS 10; I'm trying to download the iOS 10.3.1 simulator but the Apple servers are not cooperating. All my physical devices have been updated to iOS 11 so will do this as soon as I can

Comment: If you change the deploy target to iOS 10 and run in an iOS 10 simulator, you'll see it.  I used 10.3.

Comment: @BrandonMantzey answer updated based on code provided and iOS 10.3.1 simulator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155347/discussion-between-brandon-mantzey-and-ekscrypto).

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 10 and below you need to set up CGFrame for your attributed titleLabel. 
Here is the code example.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *fontAttribute = @{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"SFProText-Medium" size:15.f]};
    NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"YOUR TITLE"
    attributes:fontAttribute];
    titleLabel.attributedText = str;
    [titleLabel sizeToFit]; // This method create a frame
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;

}
```

Swift example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let title = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your title", attributes:[
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0, weight: UIFont.Weight.light)])
    titleLabel.attributedText = title
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel

}
```